# Adjust Multiple DNS PTR Zones

Tags: powershell, pointers, dns

Goal: We need to change the PTR records on 1,055 Zones.  We need to change the Host Name of every record.  Well over 10,000 entries...

We are currently forced to work with DNSCMD as we are still a 2008 R2 Domain.

To keep this discussion simple I'll only be using a zone with 1 Server in it.

Take this example server: *Thor.domain.com* with an IP of *10.128.10.5*. If you export this zone using this command:

```batch
dnscmd /enumzones > AllZones.txt

for /f %a in (AllZones.txt) do dnscmd /ZoneExport %a export\%a.txt`
```

It results in a text file that has content like this:

```
;  Database file (null) for 10.128.10.in-addr.arpa zone.
;      Zone version:  21

@            IN  SOA DomainControler.testdomain.com. hostmaster.testdomain.com. (
                 21           ; serial number
                 900          ; refresh
                 600          ; retry
                 86400        ; expire
                 3600       ) ; default TTL

;  Zone NS records
@            NS  DomainControler.testdomain.com.

;  Zone records
5            PTR Thor.domain.com.
```

Step 1 complete. Of course that script did create 1,055 different text files, one per PTR Zone.  We will be working on just one for this discussion.

I have figured out how to clean up this file to get it almost to the stage where I could use it to import it back into DNS. To prepare this file for re-import I have done some massaging of the text.

Here is my Script so far.

```bsh
$ZoneName  = Get-ChildItem -File C:\PS\DNS\PTR\export\ | % {$_.BaseName}
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -File C:\PS\DNS\PTR\export\ | % {$_.Name}

foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
  (Get-Content c:\PS\DNS\PTR\export\$filename) -replace "PTR","" -replace " ","" |
    Select-Object -Skip 24 |
    Out-File C:\PS\DNS\PTR\Output\$fileName
}
```

What this does:

1. Remove any reference to PTR
2. Removes any Spaces
3. Removes the first 24 lines of text

Results in a file that looks like this:

```
5    Thor.domain.com.
```

Also, this file is named after the zone: `10.128.10.in-addr.arpa.txt`.

The file now needs to have the zone information added to each line of text. This is where I am stuck.

The last step I am having a hard time with is taking the file name (zone information) and prepending this text at the beginning of each line in the file including a tab.

I have specified a variable `$ZoneName` which takes the file names of all the zone files but only gets the baseName (no extension).

In theory, I want to use this variable to create a file that would look like this:

```
10.128.10.in-addr.arpa    5    Thor.domain.com
```

As far as I know we will have to delete all of our PTR Zones and re-add them. This could be done in the GUI but that's a horrendous amount of work.

Once I have these files formatted as above I should then be able to use a command such as this to import them.

```batch
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=;" %%a in (PTRs2Add.txt) do (
  dnscmd domaincontroller /RecordAdd %%a %%b %%c %%d >>addPTR.log
)
```

This particular command would require me to combine all the result files into one large file.  I'm sure I could figure out a better way to parse through each zone file that I have massaged.

Of course if I have gone down a horribly wrong rabbit hole I am open for other suggestions on how to change the hostname entry on 10,000 PTR records sitting in 1,055 different zones.

Comment: So you want the line with PTR... remove the PTR and whitespace and prepend the name of the file in front of that line for every file you have in export?

Comment: Is that PTR line always the last line?

Comment: *Of course if I have gone down a horribly wrong rabbit hole I am open for other suggestions on how to change the Host Name entry on 10,000 PTR Records sitting in 1,055 different Zones :)* - build a 2012 R2 VM, export/import, use powershell, export/import back into your domain? :-|

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want to achieve, because you don't seem to change anything about the record(s). Do you want to move PTR zones to a different server/domain? Change the address? The hostname? The domain?

Comment: @Matt, Correct, I want to pre-pend the file name into the file on each line to complete the data that would be used by the script on the import.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good catch!  I omitted a -replace command by mistake.  there should be an additional one (-replace "domain.com","new-domain.com".

Answer (score 0):

Mixing batch and PowerShell and exporting/importing files shouldn't be necessary AFAICS. Write the `dnscmd` output to the output stream (vulgo STDOUT) and use regular expressions for extracting the relevant information:

```
& dnscmd /EnumZones | Where-Object {
  $_ -match '^ (\S+\.in-addr\.arpa)'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $zone = $matches[1]

  & dnscmd /ZonePrint $zone | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(\S+)\s+(?:\d+)\s+(?:PTR)\s+(\S+)'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $data    = $matches[1]
    $name    = $matches[2]
    $newname = $name.Replace('.example.org.', '.example.com.')

    & dnscmd /RecordDelete $zone $name PTR $data /f
    & dnscmd /RecordAdd $zone $newname PTR $data /f
  }
}
```

As you already suspected, [modifying a record](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc901586.aspx) consists of deleting and re-creating it.

If you need a little bit more control about which zones should be processed you may want to build objects from the zone information and put another `Where-Object` filter between that and enumerating the zone records:

```
& dnscmd /EnumZones | Where-Object {
  $_ -match '^ (\S+\.in-addr\.arpa)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S*)'
} | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
    Name       = $matches[1]
    Type       = $matches[2]
    Storage    = $matches[3]
    Properties = $matches[4]
  })
} | Where-Object {
  # filter zones (optional), e.g.:
  $_.Type -eq 'primary'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $zone = $_.Name

  & dnscmd /ZonePrint $zone | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(\S+)\s+(?:\d+)\s+(?:PTR)\s+(\S+)'
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $data    = $matches[1]
    $name    = $matches[2]
    $newname = $name.Replace('.example.org.', '.example.com.')

    & dnscmd /RecordDelete $zone $name PTR $data /f
    & dnscmd /RecordAdd $zone $newname PTR $data /f
  }
}
```